# mysql codeigniter

Tags: sql, mysql, codeigniter

How to do BETWEEN query with codeigniter's active record?

Comment: please explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

As a standalone method `$this->db->between('field_name', 'min_value', 'max_value')`, **NO** it does not exists. But you can use custom query strings in the `where()` method:

```
$this->db->where('age BETWEEN 18 AND 25', NULL);
```

Just search the CI forums, and you will find a [couple](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/169624/) of [threads](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102635/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

simple..

use this:

```
$this->db->where("sampledate between '$start' and '$end'",NULL,false);
```